# 'jpaAuditingHandler' defined in null on application startup using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading to spring boot 2.1 from 2.0.5, I am getting following error at application start up:

The bean 'jpaAuditingHandler', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

The error gets resolved if I specify following in application.yaml:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

What will this allow-bean-definition-overriding do ?

Also, I don't want to do enable that. How can I configure 'jpaAuditingHandler' to get away with this error

Comment: I see -1 on my question. Could you please explain why is that ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will get this error if you have multiple `@EnableJpaAuditing` declarations in your Spring config files.  Just declare it once.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a library, which required `@EnableJpaAuditing`. Users could have their own `@Configuration` classes, which could be declaring `@EnableJpaAuditing`. This would be leading to application context failure because of multiple `@EnableJpaAuditing` in one context.

So, we had to declare `@EnableJpaAuditing` **only if** the user context has not already declared it.

Fortunately, the Spring Boot allows conditions at context.

Next solution (in Kotlin) is the `@Configuration`, which is applied only if `@EnableJpaAuditing` was not applied.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name=["jpaAuditingHandler"])
@EnableJpaAuditing
class JpaAuditingNonConflictingDeclaration
```