# Fail to load multiple spring data jpa projects with auditing jar files into application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let me explain it with example projects.
i have one main project which don't have database connection(But holds the required dependencies for spring data jpa projects).

Now assume i have 2 spring boot projects built as jar file and want to hot load into my main project.

project structure looks below

```
 com.org.project1
    config
      configutation.java
    controller
      controllerfile.java
    domain
      entityobject.java
    repo
      entityrepository.java
```

everything works fine until i introduce EnableJPAAuditing annotation inside these jars.

since every jar has its own EnableJPAAuditing annotation, its failing.
To put this annotation into common i.e main project, i dont have database connection over there.

can somebody please help.
below is the configuration annotation in each jar
[image]

FYI:
Adding EnableJPAAuditing annotation in any one jar will works fine
Error i am getting while starting application

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if question is not clear. i can add few more info to it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for my issue. followed the answer mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133532/5845010

it worked. now i can have multiple EnableJpaAuditing annotations conditionally on every project i load.